# how to prove that $f(x^k)=k . f(x)$ for all $k\in R^+$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove that $f(x^k)=k. f(x)$ where $f$ is continues and $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. For $k\in N$ is straightforward, however I am struggling when $k=\frac{p}{q}\in Q^+$ and moreover when its irrational. My try: $f(x^{k})=f(x^{\frac{p}{q}})=f(\sqrt[q]{x^p})=f((\sqrt[q]{x})^p)=p.f(\sqrt[q]{x})=p.f(x^{q^-1})$. Any hints?

Comment: Use $y= x^{1/p}$. For irrational $r$, you use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @John sorry I didn't get it. you mean $f(xx^{1/p})=f(x)+f(x^{1/p})$ ?

Comment: $x = \left(x^{1/q}\right)^q$, so $f(x) = q\cdot f(x^{1/q})$, so ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $p\in \mathbb N$, $y=x^{\frac{1}{p}}$. $$f(x)=f(y^p)=pf(y)=pf(x^{\frac{1}{p}}),$$
hence $$f(x^{\frac{1}{p}})=\frac{1}{p}f(x)$$
and $$f(x^q)=qf(x)$$
for $q\in \mathbb Q$.

Now let $r\in \mathbb R$ and $\{r_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $r$. For all $n$ you have:$$f(x^{r_n})=r_nf(x).$$ Since $f$ and $x^q$ for $q\in \mathbb Q$ are continuous: $$rf(x)=\lim _n r_n f(x)=\lim _n f(x^{r_n})=f(x^{\lim _n r_n})=f(x^r).$$